# Best strategy to cache and store and then forward

Tags: caching, file-io, concurrency, activemq-classic, memory-mapped-files

JVM(client) sends a lot of event data to another JVM(server) via ActiveMQ message queue. The ActiveMQ server is embedded in the server JVM. If the volume of the messages is too high the client JVM needs to keep the messages in a local memory cache and if the cache overflows it needs to persist the messages in the file system. Concurrently, another thread will need to read the data from the file/cache and send it to the server jvm.
My question is: what is best way to implement this? Will memory mapped I/O help? I need to delete the data from the local file once it is gone to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid having logic to cache/persist messages on the client side since that would make things more complicated and you are kind of duplicating the same functionality happening in the server. First you need to define the maximum volume you expect and check if AMQ can handle that. Try to tune AMQ to handle high volume and use its persistence features, but all that would be on the server.

It looks like you don't care if you lose messages since you are willing to keep them in the client's memory. If that is the case you can optimize some things in AMQ to have better throughput. Here are guidelines:

http://activemq.apache.org/performance-tuning.html

If you still feel like you need to cache/persist messages in the client, I see these options:

1. Do it yourself (reinventing the wheel).
2. Embed an AMQ broker on the client side too. AMQ broker client would forward messages to AMQ broker server.
3. Use any other framework to handle messages on the client side. Akka framework might help you since they have actors with [durable mailboxes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/modules/durable-mailbox.html).

I would go for 2 or 3 doing more research on 3 to find the right framework.